# Matlab: Image plotting resolution/dpi

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I am plotting x and y coordinates together with some images but the images are becoming extremely large compared to the axis. How can i set the figure resolution or size so that an image can fit in a small axis range rather than covering the whole graph and also modify the axis range.

[image]

Figure without images (below).
[image]

Matlab code:

```
for l = 1:size of array                   
   colormap('gray'); 
   imagesc(X,Y, imrotate(imresize(img,[100 100]),180));
end
```

Comment: Have you tried adjusting plot resolution itself instead of image resolution adjustment?

Comment: Yes that is what I need! All I can find online is how to print and save. All I want is just to display the graph in high resolution so that the image would become plotted into smaller axis range ( ie between 1 and 1.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `imagesc` will plot the image using indexed coordinates (pixel spacing of 1). Note the axes limits on this figure:

[image]

You can change this by altering the [`XData` and `YData` properties of the image](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/the-image-object-and-its-properties.html?refresh=true#f2-14273).

```
him = imagesc(rand(4), 'XData', [0,1], 'YData', [0 1])
```

[image]

Notice that this changed the scaling of your image. I'm not sure what coordinate system your points are (and if you can provide a little more information I can help you better), but you can adjust the `XData` and `YData` to be the appropriate values to match your points.

Comment: The issue was that I needed to plot the x and y coordinates with crosses first than plot the images. The images were plotted using @Seuver  example.